# Symfony login form into a navbar

Tags: forms, symfony, authentication, twig, symfony4

I would like to create a login form available from all the website by the navbar which is on the top. By clicking on "login" it opens a dropdown with the login form. Still I don't really know how to proceed, I used a render twig function in my dropdown, I got my login form, but something went wrong.

when I failed to login, I obtain a simple vue of the login form with errors (normal), but only it, not the rest of the website, moreover tip "website/login" redirect me to this login form alone too.

**My files are :**

**# /src/Controller/SecurityController.php**

**# the function into "class SecurityController extends Controller"**

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
{
    if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) 
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
                        'security/login.html.twig',
                        array(
                            // last username entered by the user
                            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                            'error'         => $error,
                        )
                    );
}
```

**The twig function used in my *"navbar.html.twig"* is :**

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\SecurityController::loginAction')) }}
```

**The *"login.html.twig"* look like this :**

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path("login_check") }}" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" required="required" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" placeholder="Adresse email" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="password" required="required" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="Mot de passe" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="_remember_me" name="_remember_me" checked />
        <label for="_remember_me">Se souvenir de moi</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="login">Se connecter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is it possible to do what I want? (without ajax?)

Comment: If you wants to do it by page redirect then you can make a eventListener which handle failed authentication and refirect somewhere else where your whole website view exist and gave a flash message about failure.

But I suggest you to use Ajax for this case as you loading form in a dropdown  so if you page redirect then the dropdown will be collapsed off  so after failer it will be a bad experience to the user. So it will be better if  you handle all this in ajax and only after success the page will be redirect to success page.
thank you

Comment: I think you're better of building a [traditional login](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) form, and have your navbar-login simply post to that other route. The experience will be that on valid login, everything works as expected. On failure, the user will land on the login page with an error message. This way you don't need to render a controller response (which you're better of avoiding anyways).